# Adding a speed vector to a position vector only works with integers

Tags: python, vector, pygame

In using this script for simple vector math, I can add the speed vector when the values are integers such as 1 and 2, but when the speed vector is initialized with a float .5 there is no movement. As far as I can tell python doesn't require declaring float or int, but I have a feeling that the resulting number is being truncated

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())

rectangle = pygame.Rect(65, 45, 50, 50)

class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __iadd__(self, vector):
        self.x += vector.x
        self.y += vector.y
        return self

    def __isub__(self, vector):
        self.x -= vector.x
        self.y -= vector.y
        return self

    def copy(self, vector):
        self.x = vector.x
        self.y = vector.y

speed = Vector2D(.5, .5)
going = True

while going:
#Handle Input Events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            going = False


    rectangle.left += speed.x
    rectangle.top += speed.y

    #Draw Everything
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), rectangle, 1)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: rectangle coords maybe snap to ints as theres no such thing as a half pixel ... just make a position list  position=[0,0] and modify that

Comment: Have another `Vector2D position` that you update. Cast to int if needed when you set `rect.topleft = position`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is nothing like *half a pixel*, the `Rect` class truncates the decimal of the floats you are adding.

So keeping track of the position within the `Vector2D` class is a better Idea:

```
class Vector2D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.vx = vx
        self.vy = vy

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy

    def copyto(self, rect):
        rect.x = int(round(self.x,0)) 
        rect.y = int(round(self.y,0))


speed = Vector2D(100, 100, .5, .5)
```

And have this:

```
speed.update()
speed.copyto(rectangle)
```

In place of:

```
rectangle.left += speed.x
rectangle.top += speed.y
```